# Maple, chemical equation balancing

Tags: maple

input is a chemical equation like that

```
aKMnO4 + bHCl = cKCl + dMnCl2 + eH2O + fCl2
// a, b, c, d, e, f are numbers.
```

I tried to solve this problem by solve some equations:

```
a = c // K
a = d // Mn
4*a = e // O
b = e // H
b = c + 2*d + 2*f // Cl
```

It works, but i have to enter these equations as a input in my code.

Is there any way to find a, b, c, d, e, f just by the chemical equation input?

Comment: Do the code blocks consist of *Maple* code? It looks like you use `//` as a comment delimiter but for comments in Maple the delimiter is a hash (`#`). Also, it is preferred to use a multiplication operator (`*`) - that way it can be understood in both Maple notation ("code") and 2D notation (it is not obvious that `KMnO4` are three (four?) objects).

Comment: @Therkel It is not really Maple code, i just show my idea. These equation will be solve by solve function in maple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but you need to rewrite your chemical equation with + and * in the compounds so H2O becomes H*2+O e.g.  Your equation

```
a KMnO4 + b HCl = c KCl + d MnCl2 + e H2O + f Cl2
```

here becomes:

```
eq:=a*(K+Mn+O*4) + b*(H+Cl) = c*(K+Cl) + d*(Mn+Cl*2) + e*(H*2+O) + f*(Cl*2);
```

They you can get equations for a-f by equating coefficients:

```
elems := [ K, Mn, O, H, Cl ];
eqr := collect(expand(rhs(eq)), elems);
eql := collect(expand(lhs(eq)), elems);
eqs := zip(`=`, map2(coeff, eql, elems), map2(coeff, eqr, elems));
```

It would be an interesting project to build something that could recognize the chemical symbols and parse them more automatically into equations.

Comment: Thank you, I get your idea. It's really helpful. I found out that the result when i `solve(eqs)` depends on one of `{a, b, c, d, e,f}` like this `{a = d, b = 8*d, c = d, d = d, e = 4*d, f = (5/2)*d}` .Therefore, I add equation `a = 1` to `eqs` by `eqs := [op(eqs),a = 1]` to get all number value result. It works well. By the way, I'm working on a project some way like what you said.